# How to scroll to current day after render calebdar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar.io.I want to scroll up to the current date after the render of the calendar on listMonth view.

calendar code:

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    columnFormat = 'ddd';
    defaultView = 'listMonth';
    left = 'prev,next';
    right = 'month,listMonth';
} else {
    columnFormat = 'dddd';
    defaultView = 'month';
    left = 'prev';
    right = 'next';
}
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: left,
        center: 'title',
        right: right
    },
    timeFormat: 'H:mm',
    columnFormat: columnFormat,
    defaultView: defaultView,
    events: {
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'events_list',
            security: MyAjax.security,
        },
    },
    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
        if (event.url) {
            window.open(event.url, "_blank");
            return false;
        }
    },
});
```

Please help me to do it.

Example: https://jewlife.by/

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I tried all the methods described in Google, but nothing happened

Comment: look at my answer i added it for you, you must be using date as string rather than moment object, see the last 2 line in the script that is the correct way how to navigate the calendar to a specific date `2014-05-01` 3 years back @SiamionGavrilenko

Answer (score 3):

Muhammad's answer is fine for most of FullCalendar's views, but alas the `listMonth` view does not support that approach for jumping to a particular day in the current month.

Instead, you need to programmatically scroll to the current day. Something like the following will work fine:

```
// Initialise the calendar
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
        if (view.name === "listMonth") {
            var viewStartDate = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getDate");
            var target = $(".fc-listMonth-view .fc-list-heading[data-date=" + viewStartDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "]");
            if (target.length) {
                $(".fc-listMonth-view .fc-scroller").scrollTop(target.position().top);
            }
        }
    },
    // Other initial settings here
});
```

Tested and working as of FullCalendar v3.9.0.

Comment: how could you say `listMonth` does not support this approach the demo above is with the same view you are talking about

Comment: Your demo appears to be broken so I was unable to test it, however in my experience using the `gotoDate` method only jumps to the given month, not the given date. If you have many events on each day, you still need to scroll all the way down to the correct date manually. The code I posted above solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `goToDate()` if you want to navigate to a date after the calendar has loaded, via the click of a button, it moves the calendar to an arbitrary date.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date )
```

*Note: `date` can be a [`Moment](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/) object or anything the Moment constructor accepts.*

Or if you like the calendar to load on a specific date then you should use the `defaultDate` option while initializing the calendar.

You can learn more [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2017-11-12',
    defaultView: 'listMonth',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{
        title: 'Old Day Event',
        start: '2014-05-01'
      }, {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2017-11-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2017-11-07',
        end: '2017-11-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2017-11-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2017-11-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2017-11-11',
        end: '2017-11-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2017-11-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2017-11-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2017-11-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2017-11-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2017-11-12T17:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2017-11-12T20:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2017-11-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2017-11-28'
      }
    ]

  });

  var local = $.fullCalendar.moment('2014-05-01T12:00:00');
  calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', local);

});
```

```css
#goto {}
```

```html
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.7.0/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.7.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.7.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.7.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<p>calendar is navigated to previous date November in 2014 after loading on 2017 by default </p>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I tried this method, it does not work. Or I do not correctly integrate it into my code.

Comment: how are you calling it , add the section of the code in your original post under EDIT heading in the end

Comment: how can i run function goto automatically, after render calendar?

Comment: and use defaultView = 'listMonth'

Comment: I don't know you event visited the Docs for the fullcalendar if you want to use the `listView` you just need to add the option `defaultView:'listMonth'` and to run it automatically you can remove the click binding and just call it inline after you initialize the calendar , but I don't know why you are not using `defaultDate` to load the calendar in the previous or any other date, instead of going/navigating to the specific date separately after loading the calendar, I have updated the example for you to load `listMonth` along with using the `goToDate()` after loading the calendar.

Comment: i think, that i must to use here ScrollTo script, but i dont understand how to do it

Comment: I can confirm that the `listMonth` view does not support this method, and you need to manually implement `scrollTo` logic to achieve this.

Comment: To further clarify my comment regarding `gotoDate` not supporting the `listMonth` view: it works, but not in the way the OP wants it to. It won't scroll to the current date, it will only switch to the given month.